# oracle query to fetch the last 4 records from the table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have an table named employee in which several jobs run a background that insert the data into the table ow please advise the query by which i can fetch the last 4 records of the from the table , I am using oracle as a database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sub query for this like

```
select * from ( select * from tableName order by id desc ) where ROWNUM <= 4;
```